# Control multiple BLE peripherals with one central

Tags: node.js, bluetooth-lowenergy, mbed, nrf51

I am pretty new to IoT and BLE. What I want to achieve is to write on GATT characteristic of at least 100 peripheral devices simultaneously or in a very short period of time(i.e. less than 100ms). Currently my peripherals are Ble nano (nRF51822) with custom GATT service running on them. I am using my Mac as central BLE. I am using Node.js and noble to implement the central. I want to know if such thing is possible at all and if possible, please link me to an example code. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should note that Bluetooth chips for computers are usually (quite arbitrarily) limited to only a few simultaneous connections. Common values are between 3 and 14. Even if you connect a few at a time, send the characteristic value, disconnect and then connect next devices it would be impossible to do this within 100 ms. If you want to send the same data to everyone you should instead let your computer advertise and the nrf devices scan. That way you broadcast the data instead.

Comment: Thanks Emil for your answer. I need to be able to control the peripherals individually also, so the solution you suggested to let the computer advertise don't seem practical to me. BTW I am using the computer for prototyping and it will be replaced by BLE Chips later in production.